# How does VS intellisense know about the properties an anonymous class have at compile time?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, anonymous-class

I can't find anything and would still like to understand how does the intelli-sense mechanism in VS know about the properties of an anonymous class...

Just a basic example:

```
var anonymousObj = new[] { new { foo = "stack", boo = false },
                    new { foo = "overflow", boo = true }};

foreach (var item in anonymousObj)
{
    // how does VS intelli-sense already know the properties?
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.foo, item.boo);
}
```

or [another dummy example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/anonymous-types-in-C-Sharp/)

What confuses me the most if that afaik, we can initialize anonymous classes with dynamic content, Linq expressions etc.

Like if you were working with query expressions, say populating the `anonymous` obj based on some query etc. how does intelli-sense already know all the properties names? Like, as soon as you type `item.` you can see both `foo` and `boo`?

I was always convinced that there is no way to know that until the run-time.

> For Anonymous type, Visual studio able to show intellisense because
>   type is known at the time compilation whereas intellisense is not
>   available with dynamic because type is defines at runtime.

But how does it know the type of `var` at compilation time?

I am sorry if I have missed something here, if it's a dumb question and I simply have missed something, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no name for an anonymous type *that is a valid identifier when writing the code*.  However, when compiled, the anonymous type is turned into a regular named type, given a name, given a definition with properties corresponding to what it needs to have as per your definition, and then that new named type is used in place of the anonymous type everywhere.

There is nothing dynamic about anonymous types; they are entirely statically typed.  An analysis of the code alone provides all of the information needed to provide all of the information that Intellisense is providing.

Comment: yea but at the time of writing code the intelli-sense already knows but I haven't even compiled yet :/

Comment: @mehow But all of the information is there, statically, to provide the needed information.  And in effect it *is* compiling the code, or at least performing the lexing and semantic analysis steps, while simply ignoring the "translation to IL" steps.

Comment: @mehow, I suspect intellisense uses the same methods the compiler does, in the background, to figure it out.  You know, the DRY principle :)